# How to informally say "Sending love to you and your family" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request, salutation

Best way to say "Sending love to you (female) and your family" in German? Our families are very close, so it should be informal.

Comment: **To close voters:** isn't this more of a phrase-request of the kind we do allow here?

Comment: As a general rule, when you would mention *love* in English outside of a romantic relationship, you would normally use something much "weaker" in German, such as *greetings* (*Grüße*) or similar. I think this has been discussed in some other questions that could be linked here; I am not sure there is an exact duplicate, though.

Comment: What do you bring up on your own? Where do you struggle? P.S.: Die zweite Person Singular hat kein Geschlecht, zumindest weder im Deutschen, noch im Englischen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a German native i would say: 'Alles Liebe für Dich und Deine Familie' which is more personal than 'Liebe Grüße...' and still different from meaning romantic love.

Answer (score 4):

> "Beste/Herzliche/Liebe Grüße an dich und deine ganze Familie"

"Beste/Herzliche/Liebe Grüße" are more personal than "Viele Grüße". I think, "Liebe Grüße" is with friends always ok.

> "Tausend Küsse (an euch)"

is OK for very close friends or for areas where kisses on the cheeks are a normal way to greet someone.

> "Von Herzen alles Gute für dich und deine Familie"

That is a very strong wish. I wouldn't use it often and it is more for special occasions (e.g you won't see/hear the person for a long time or they just got a baby or ...).

---

A comment on capitalizing "Du", "Deine" and "Dich". You can write "Du", "Deine" and "Dich" capitalized in letters, but you don't have to ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/gross-oder-kleinschreibung-von--em-du-du--em--und--em-ihr-ihr--em--1)) (thanks to @chirlu for the correction), but as @jera pointed out "Sie" and "Ihnen" have to be capitalized in letters ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/gross-oder-kleinschreibung-von--em-sie-sie--em-)).

Comment: More exactly, before 1996, _du_ etc. were _allowed_ to be capitalized in letters; between 1996 and 2006, they _had to written in lowercase_; and since 2006, it’s the same rule as before 1996, i.e. they may be capitalized (in letters only) if the author so chooses.

Comment: Mhm never seen "Taused Küsse" at all - also not for very informal or close relations (that although kissing on the cheeks was common everywhere I lived, just a question of how many). Might be regional - it is after all, a very common french phrase to end letters.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of variants possible.

I would say "Viele Grüße auch an Deine Familie" or "Viele Grüße an Dich und Deine Familie" or "Viele Grüße an die ganze Familie". The last one would be short and include both: her and her family.

To have it with more "english love": "Liebe Grüße ..."

Comment: I feel "Viele Grüße" still sounds pretty flat and does not come close to "Sending love to you".

Answer (score 1):

I feel "Viele Grüße" still sounds pretty flat and upstage and does not come close to "Sending love to you" but rather to "Kind regards" or similar.

I recommend in ascending strength:

> Dir und Deiner Familie alles Gute
>   Dir und Deiner Familie alles Liebe
>   Ich wünsche Dir und deiner Familie liebe Grüße
>   Liebe Grüße an Dich und deine Familie

Comment: I would rather use "sende liebe Grüße" than "wünsche liebe Grüße"

Answer (score -1):

> Sei ganz lieb gegrüßt!

is one of my personal favourites. Another one is:

> Ich drücke dich ganz herzlich!

Comment: How would this incorporate the family, as requested by the asker?

Comment: Welcome on this site! Please note, it should be _Ich drücke **dich** ganz herzlich._ (accusative). Furthermore, it helps your readers to distinguish between the German and English parts of your post, if you use different [formatting](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) - italic font, for example. You can (and should) edit your post accordingly.